# Why is $.ajax error handler called on HTTP 200 response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Despite receiving a 200 response, this code always ends up in the error handler. Using curl, this is the response from the server. Note that I am explicitly specifying a dataType of html.

> Using jQuery 1.11.2

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "/sendmail?to=" + mailto + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html'

      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Mail sent to ' + mailto);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Failed to send mail to ' + mailto);
      });
```

```
curl -v --data "to=multi4@tim.com&subject=Your%20account&body=%3Cp%3EHi,%20Tim" http://localhost:9000/sendmail
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fd1c8803000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fd1c8803000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 9000 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /sendmail HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:9000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 397
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 397 out of 397 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< cache-control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 0
* Server Development/2.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Development/2.0
< Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 22:21:50 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with the HTML document that the server says it is returning being 0 bytes long.

Comment: what's the value of  `jqXHR`, `textStatus` and `errorThrown`?

Comment: Inspect the actual request in network tab of browser console for further clues. Content length 0 seems suspicious

Comment: $.fail != hxr.onerror, jQuery goes above and beyond low-level network errors.

Comment: Could be because you're sending the data payload via query string (GET) in your JavaScript. Try using `url: /sendmail` and `data: { to: mailto, subject: subject, body: body }`. Your cURL request probably works because your data is sent in the POST request body

Comment: textStatus and errorThrown give me nothing. It's a pretty barebones service for occasional emails to an administrator.

Comment: @Phil - you could be right there. I will see if I can do a cURL post with params and/or put the data into the request body. Good thinking!

Comment: @timbo easy way to test; passing `-G` to curl forces a get request with data in the query string